# how to get first word in string and convert to int

Tags: c

I have a char array, and I want to get the first number from it.

e.g if my char array is 34 400 43 33.  I want 34 as in int.

```
int FirstInt(char chars[])
{
    return atoi(chars.substr(0, bursts.find(' ')));
}
```

I was thinkign something like this but it is not valid.  ANy ideas?

Comment: Did you read some good book about programming in C ?

Comment: the language you use in your sample is not C.

Comment: I realize that, I'm just explainging what I would like to do

Comment: What if the string is not in a valid format? How would you report an error with this signature?

Comment: `I want 34 as in int` Do you mean an array of char arrays? (array of strings). If not your example `chars[]` would contains: `[3][4][4][0][0][4][3][3][3]` and it would be very hard to get "34" out of that as the first "number", or are the blanks supposed to be spaces? `' '`

Comment: Quite easy apparently according to timrau's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int FirstInt(char chars[])
{
    int x;
    sscanf(chars, "%d", &x);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: ok this is essentially what I want, I also want to remove that first int from the string

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to tokenize the string or use sscanf if all you want is the first number:

```
return atoi(str);
```

**From the man page**

> The atoi() function converts the initial portion of the string pointed
>   to by nptr to int

Which means it will stop when it finds a non-numeric character, like a white space.

**Edit**:
Note that it's impossible to detect errors with atoi, since it returns 0 on error in some implementations and doesn't set errno (AFAIK), so it's probably better to use *strtol*
See this link [Converting Strings to Numbers](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Converting)

Comment: what if the first characters are not numbers?

Comment: @KevinDTimm That's a good point, but the OP asked specifically about atoi and not about the safest way to convert an int, I will add that to the answer anyway, thanks!